# Allocating the houseworks is a NP-complete problem

Tags: computability, np-complete

$k$ firends are living in a living community. There are $n$ houseworks that have to be allocated. The estimated time for each housework is $t_1, t_2, \dots , t_n$ respectively. The friends want to share the houseworks so that each of them will finish with the work in the time $T$.

I want to show that the problem is NP-complete.

To prove this do we maybe reduce the Bin Packing Problem to the above one?

At the Bin Packing Problem a set of numbers $a_1,\dots ,a_n,B,k$ is given. It asks if $a_1,\dots ,a_n$ can be allocated into the $k$ bins of size $B$ , so that the sum in each bin is $\leq B$.

For the reduction we consider the numbers $a_i$ as the times $t_i$, the $k$ bins as the $k$ students and the size $B$ as the time $T$.

Is my idea correct?

Comment: That looks good to me.  Just to be sure: to show the housework problem is NP-complete, you have to take an NP-complete problem, such as the bin packing one, and transform it into an instance of the housework problem.  Hence the given data is $a_1, ..., a_n, B, k$ from the bin packing, and you can choose $t_1, ..., t_n, T, k$ for the housework.

Comment: So, is the whole proof the following? $$$$ A non-deterministic Turing machine guesses an allocation of the houseworks und checks if each of the allocated houseworks can be done in time $T$. For that the Turing machine needs polynomial time, and especially $k\cdot n$. Is this correct? Therefore, the problem is in NP. @Shagnik

Comment: To show that the pronlem is NP-hard, we reduce the Bin Paching Problem to that problem. 
At the Bin Packing Problem a set of numbers $a_1,\dots ,a_n,B,k$ is given. It asks if $a_1,\dots ,a_n$ can be allocated into the $k$ bins of size $B$ , so that the sum in each bin is $\leq B$.

Comment: So, when $(a_1,\dots ,a_n,B,k)$ is the input for the Bin Packing Problem and when we consider the $a_i,\dots ,a_n$ as the times $t_1,\dots ,t_n$ of each housework, the size $B$ as the time $T$ and the $k$ bins as the $k$ students, we have that the allocation problem has a solution iff the Bin Packing problem has a solution.Since there is no algorithm that solves the Bin packing problem in polynomial time, there is neither an algorithm that solves in polynomial time the allocation problem.Therefore,the allocation problem is NP-complete. Is everything correct?Could I improve something? @Shagnik

Comment: I think everything is indeed correct.  Just a slight typo - in the last comment you have an $a_i$ that should be an $a_1$.

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much!! :-) @Shagnik

Answer (score 1):

If $k=2$ and $t_1+\ldots+t_n=2T$, your problem becomes an instance of the NP-complete [Partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), so your problem is NP-complete as well.

Comment: So, we can use both problems, Bin Packing and Partition Problem, for the reduction, or not?

Comment: Definitely. Actually, you can use **any** NP-complete problem in the reduction, the only problem is how complicated this reduction would be.